# Removing 'kubuntu-restricted-extas' (Or: Understanding 'apt-get autoremove' in general)

Tags: apt, package-management, kubuntu, uninstall, ppa

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu (respectively Kubuntu) and Linux in general. Yet, some thing is causing trouble to me. Excuse me, if this has been answered before, but I somehow can't put together those pieces in a way that I can actually understand.

So, I've recently installed the kubuntu-restricted-extras (via `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-restricted-extas`) for playing MP3 files, watching DVD movies etc.. There's one thing yet that has kept me bothering for almost two weeks now:

Just in theory: Assuming I want to remove those packages `kubuntu-restricted-extras` is refering to... how am I supposed do actually do this?

I've heard about `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove <packagename>`, but this one's just removing the metapackage itself - at least for me.

It's not that I'm annoyed by having these packages installed on my PC, yet I'm very interested in learning how to deal with this "autoremove" function in general.

For another instance, `'apt-get autoremove --purge quassel'` leaves packages like `quassel-data` installed on my machine. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your help!

PS: While writing, I came up with another question, this one's rather small though. I know, there are many PPAs out there, often containing additional or newer versions of various pieces of software... Assuming I want to remove one of these additional sources with, let's say, an unstable mesa build, how do I revert those packages like xorg, mesa, etc. (Let's say I've added this xorg-edgers PPA) back to the versions in the actual Ubuntu repositories? That'd also be great to know.

Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Regarding the PS, see http://askubuntu.com/a/313/158442.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense to me, thanks :)

There's just this other thing that's bothering me. Let's see if someone knows a solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Logs**

Ubuntu community: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles

The apt log: /var/log/apt/...

The dpkg log: /var/log/dpkg.log...

**Keeping own logs - the logsave**

```
LOGSAVE(8)                                  System Manager's Manual                                  LOGSAVE(8)

NAME
       logsave - save the output of a command in a logfile

SYNOPSIS
       logsave [ -asv ] logfile cmd_prog [ ... ]

DESCRIPTION
       The  logsave program will execute cmd_prog with the specified argument(s), and save a copy of its output
       to logfile.  If the containing directory for logfile does not exist, logsave will accumulate the  output
       in memory until it can be written out.  A copy of the output will also be written to standard output.
```

**At here**

When installing/upgrading/removing something I will use the logsave to save the output to the human readable file.

If I want to remove the 'kubuntu-restricted-extras' I would look the log file:

```
Log of sudo apt-get install kubuntu-restricted-extras libdvdcss2 
Sun Apr 20 17:07:16 2014

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra freepats gstreamer1.0-libav
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
  kubuntu-restricted-addons lame liba52-0.7.4 libass4 libchromaprint0
  libcroco3 libdc1394-22 libdca0 libenca0 libfaad2 libfftw3-double3 libflite1
  libfluidsynth1 libgme0 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgtkglext1
  libk3b6-extracodecs libkate1 libmad0 libmimic0 libmms0 libmodplug1
  libmpeg2-4 libmpg123-0 libnspr4-0d libnss3-1d libofa0 libopenal-data
  libopenal1 libopencore-amrnb0 libopencore-amrwb0 libopencv-calib3d2.4
  libopencv-contrib2.4 libopencv-core2.4 libopencv-features2d2.4
  libopencv-flann2.4 libopencv-highgui2.4 libopencv-imgproc2.4
  libopencv-legacy2.4 libopencv-ml2.4 libopencv-objdetect2.4
  libopencv-video2.4 libpangox-1.0-0 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsidplay1
  libsoundtouch0 libspandsp2 libsrtp0 libswscale2 libtbb2 libtwolame0
  libvo-aacenc0 libvo-amrwbenc0 libwildmidi-config libwildmidi1 libzbar0
  nepomuk-core-ffmpegextractor oxideqt-codecs-extra unrar
Suggested packages:
  frei0r-plugins libchromaprint-tools python-acoustid libfftw3-bin
  libfftw3-dev libportaudio2 libroar-compat2 librsvg2-bin sidplay-base
  xsidplay srtp-utils
Recommended packages:
  flashplugin-installer libavcodec-extra-53
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra freepats gstreamer1.0-libav
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
  kubuntu-restricted-addons kubuntu-restricted-extras lame liba52-0.7.4
  libass4 libchromaprint0 libcroco3 libdc1394-22 libdca0 libdvdcss2 libenca0
  libfaad2 libfftw3-double3 libflite1 libfluidsynth1 libgme0
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgtkglext1 libk3b6-extracodecs libkate1
  libmad0 libmimic0 libmms0 libmodplug1 libmpeg2-4 libmpg123-0 libnspr4-0d
  libnss3-1d libofa0 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopencore-amrnb0
  libopencore-amrwb0 libopencv-calib3d2.4 libopencv-contrib2.4
  libopencv-core2.4 libopencv-features2d2.4 libopencv-flann2.4
  libopencv-highgui2.4 libopencv-imgproc2.4 libopencv-legacy2.4
  libopencv-ml2.4 libopencv-objdetect2.4 libopencv-video2.4 libpangox-1.0-0
  librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsidplay1 libsoundtouch0 libspandsp2 libsrtp0
  libswscale2 libtbb2 libtwolame0 libvo-aacenc0 libvo-amrwbenc0
  libwildmidi-config libwildmidi1 libzbar0 nepomuk-core-ffmpegextractor
  oxideqt-codecs-extra unrar
0 upgraded, 69 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 52.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 95.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

and copy&paste the file list to the

```
sudo apt-get purge <files>
```